# Add Django elements locally to ManyToMany fields without saving them in the database, comparable to the setattr function, only for M2M fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was looking to see if there was a way to add local items to a ManyToMany field without storing them in the database.
I want to be able to do the same with a ManyToMany field as I would with a ForeignKeyField or other fields of a Django model.
There is a function

```
setattr (obj, field.name, <newValue>)
```

for these fields. These changes are not saved in the database, but I can access them in templates, for example.

I would be very happy if someone could give me a hint whether there is something similar for ManyToMany Fields. I've struggled with this problem for quite a while and haven't found anything about it.

Thanks in advance :)